# System.ArgumentException: 'No headers to add (Parameter 'header')'

Tags: c#, specflow

I am trying out `Specflow` and this is my scenario

```
Scenario: Calculate user age from date of birth
    When I fill details
    | Name | DateOfBirth | 
    | John | 2000-01-01  | 
    | Mike | 2001-01-01  | 
    Then user age is calculated
    | Name | DateOfBirth | Age |
    | John | 2000-01-01  | 21  |
    | Mike | 2001-01-01  | 20  |
```

and this is my steps

```
[Binding]
public class GetAgeFromDobSteps
{
    private IEnumerable<User> actualUsers = new Table().CreateSet<User>();

    [When(@"I fill details")]
    public void WhenIFillDetails(Table table)
    {
        actualUsers = table.CreateSet<User>();

        foreach (var actualUser in actualUsers)
        {
            actualUser.CalculateAge();
        }
    }

    [Then(@"user age is calculated")]
    public void ThenUserAgeIsCalculated(Table table)
    {
        var expectedUsers = table.CreateSet<User>();
        
        expectedUsers.Should().BeEquivalentTo(actualUsers);
    }
}
```

But when I run it, there is an error at `private IEnumerable<User> actualUsers = new Table().CreateSet<User>();`

The error is `System.ArgumentException: 'No headers to add (Parameter 'header')'`

Comment: You are actually assigning `actualUsers` in `WhenIFillDetails` step. Just leave field `actualUsers` unassigned when declaring - simply: `private IEnumerable<User> actualUsers;`. Your exception happens because you're trying to create set of values from empty table.

Comment: Why not just initialise like this: `private IEnumerable<User> actualUsers = Enumerable.Empty<User>();`? Or just omit the initialisation altogether, considering `actualUsers` is assigned to in `WhenIFillDetails`?

Answer (score 1):

The `new Table().CreateSet<User>();` line assumes it is a Table object parsed from a well formed feature file. In this case, you are just initializing a new Table object with no rows or columns. This is the cause of the error.

Since you are using `actualUsers` as part of an assertion, just initialize it to an empty collection:

```
public class GetAgeFromDobSteps
{
    private IEnumerable<User> actualUsers = Enumerable.Empty<User>();
```

This should at least guard against annoying `NullReferenceException`s from being thrown and worse case scenario you assert against an empty collection of `actualUsers`.